# Dose "optional stopping theorem" imply "optional sampling theorem"?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose $X$ is a martingale,$\tau$ and $\sigma$ are two stopping times which satisfy (a)$\sigma\le\tau$ and (b)the "optional stopping theorem" holds,that is to say:

$$\mathbb E[X_\sigma]=\mathbb E[X_0],\mathbb E[X_\tau]=\mathbb E[X_0] ---(1)$$

Could we get the "optional sampling theorem":

$$\mathbb E[X_\tau|\mathcal F_\sigma]=X_\sigma ---(2)$$
by(1)?

---

What I really want to say is the following :

There are many conditions leads to (1) such as :

> $\tau$ is bounded
>
> **or** $X$ is UI
>
> **or** $\mathbb E[\tau]<\infty $ and bounded increments
>
> **or** $|X_{\tau\wedge n} | $ is bounded
>
> **or** $|X|$ is bounded.
>
> etc.

(apply bounded convergence theorem /dominate convergence theorem to interchange the
limit and expectation in $ \lim\mathbb E[X_{\tau\wedge n}]=\mathbb  E[X_0]$ )

But I have only seen two conditions leads to (2):

> $\tau$ is bounded **or**$X$ is UI

I wonder the other conditions can leads to (2),moreover whether any conditions lead to (1) can lead to (2) and whether (1) itself can lead to (2).

Comment: Do you assume that $(1)$ holds for any two stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$ or for two fixed stopping times?

Comment: @saz two fixed stopping times that satisfy (1)

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this one right now.

Comment: I know that they are equivalent if we do not fix the stopping times $\sigma$, $\tau$ (i.e. if $(1)$ holds for all $\sigma \leq \tau$, then $(2)$ holds for all $\sigma \leq \tau$). But I'm not sure whether we can fix them. And no, unfortunately, I don't have any reference...

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in my comments: If $(1)$ holds for *all* stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$, then $(2)$ holds for stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$. By "fixed" I mean that $(1)$ does not hold for *all* stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$, but for two (fixed) stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$.

Comment: @saz I updated my post,do I make myself clear?

Comment: Well, yes. But, unfortunately, I still don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: @user166445 Take a symmetric random walk $X$($\pm 1$ with equal proba), $\sigma = 0$ and $\tau$ reaching time of level $1$, then $|X_{\tau\wedge n}|$ is bounded, but $EX_\tau \neq EX_0$